# jQuery SlideToggle - Detectar aberto/fechado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de retirar a classe "ativo" de *"liToggle"* caso fechasse um SlideToggle.

Tentei usar `is(':hidden')` mas sem sucesso. Se eu coloco logo após a condicional de aberto, ele fecha na mesma hora. Estou sem idéias para a lógica.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$("aside #menu-busca ul > li a").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == "#"){

        var ulToggle = $(this).parent().children("ul");
        var liToggle = $(this).parent();
        ulToggle.slideToggle("slow");

        // * Se estiver aberto
        if (ulToggle.is(":visible")){
            $(liToggle).addClass("ativo");
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `ulToggle` é uma coleção de vários elementos certo? qual deles queres saber se está visivel? Coloca um jsFiddle que fica mais fácil de perceber o problema.

Comment: Verifica se o valor css display é block.

Comment: @Sergio, Segue! http://codepen.io/maykelesser/pen/RKdgvY... quero saber se a li clicada está visível ou não.

Comment: @MaykelEsser http://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/vgPJgb

Comment: @Sergio vi que você colocou um console.log para verificar se está aberto ou fechado, porém, veja que se eu fecho, ele retorna 2 booleanos (true e true). Se ele não é mais visible, por que está retornando TRUE ainda?

Comment: @MaykelEsser http://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/wgOrWd tinha 2 console.log nesse código. Tinha movido para a primeira linha pois ai sabes com certeza que o slideToggle ainda não começou. Porem pode ainda estar a correr um slide toggle, por isso o melhor seria ter uma flag. O que queres fazer no código depois de saber se está aberto e/ou fechado?

Comment: @Sergio Quando o SlideToggle estiver aberto, adicionar uma classe "ativo" na LI clicada. Isso eu já consegui fazer. Quando fechar, gostaria que ela fosse removida. Tentei com ELSE, is(":hidden"), mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#collapseDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   console.log("Opened")
});

$('#collapseDiv').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   console.log("Closed")
});
```